# Converting nested for loop into lower than O(n^3)

Tags: c, time-complexity, big-o

So, I have this code and I need to make it run on a time complexity of less than O(n^3). I've just started learning about complexity and I really have no idea what to do.

```
int n, i, j, k, x=0;
printf("Type n: \n");
scanf("%d",&n);


for(i=1; i<n; i++)
{
    for(j=1; j<i; j++)
    {
        for(k=1; k<j; k++)
        {
            x=x+1;
        }
    }
}
printf("%d\n",x);
```

I think I get why it's O(n^3), but I don't really know how to make it more efficient. I tried turning it into a recursive function, is it possible?

Comment: There's undoubtedly a closed formula in terms of `n` that would dramatically speed it up.  It'll be `((a * n + b) * n + c) * n + d` for suitable values of a, b, c, d — a simple cubic equation.  A recursive function wouldn't speed things up, but could be made to work.

Comment: *"I think I get why it's more than O(n^3)"* Actually, the code you have is O(n^3).

Comment: Yeah, that's what I meant, wrote it wrong, thanks for pointing it out though. This time-complexity thing bugs my brain

Comment: @NathanDanzmann Just to be absolutely clear, is the goal to compute the final value of `x`, or is the goal to do something with each combination of `i,j,k`?

Comment: Well, the x value needs to be the same output as those nested for loops.
The goal is to make it more efficient

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're adding 1 to the result for each i, j, k with 0 < k < j < i < n. There's choose(n-1, 3) such values of i, j, k (one for each subset of size 3 of {1, 2, ..., n-1}). (Here "choose" in the binomial coefficient function).

Thus, you can replace your loop-based computation with choose(n-1, 3) which is `(n - 1)(n - 2)(n - 3) / 6` if `n` is positive.

```
int n;
printf("Type n: \n");
scanf("%d",&n);
printf("%d\n", n > 0 ? (n-1)*(n-2)*(n-3)/6 : 0);
```

This is O(1) to compute the result, and O(log N) to output it (since the result has O(log N) digits).

Comment: Well, that is a perfect equation, works beautifully.
I'm just not sure I understood the math you used to find (n-1)*(n-2)*(n-3)/6.
(n-1)*(n-2)*(n-3) I understood by the explanation of rrauenza here below, in which they are zero roots...

Comment: @NathanDanzmann if you're interested, there is some explanation here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/658250/number-of-strictly-increasing-sequences-of-length-k-with-elements-from-1-2 .

Comment: To be honest, I only noticed the roots after @PaulHankin revealed the formula ...

Comment: For extra efficiency, you can replace `n > 0` with `n > 3` :-)

Comment: Well, that solves all my doubts, thank you very much @PaulHankin

Answer (score 2):

Your current function is just a lousy `O(n^3)` way to calculate some mathematical function ...

```
In   Out
0    0
1    0
2    0
3    0
4    1
5    4
6    10
7    20
8    35
9    56
10   84
```

`x` will end up being equal to the number of iterations.

Your assignment is likely to reinterpret that for loop into an equation.

We know that the outer loop will execute its block `(n-1)` times.  The next inner loop will execute its block a total of `1+2+..+(n-2)` times.  [That's](http://mathcentral.uregina.ca/QQ/database/QQ.02.06/jo1.html) `(n-1)(n-2)/2` times.  *(At this point I get stuck myself, none of my extrapolations get (n-1)(n-2)(n-3)/6)*

Another way: Since we know that 1, 2, 3 all are zero roots, we also know the function at *least* is `(n - 1)(n - 2)(n - 3)`.  Solve for `n=4` and you get `1/6` as the constant factor.

Answer (score 1):

I refactored your loop as follows:

```
for(i=1; i<n-2; i++)
{
    x = x + ( ( i * ( i + 1 ) ) / 2 );
}
```

This works because `( ( i * ( i + 1 ) ) / 2 )` = sum of all values in the series 1 through i.

You inner most loop (using variable k) is the equivalent of adding the value of j to x. Your second loop (using variable j) is then the equivalent of calculating the sum of the series 1 through i.

So I've replaced your second and third loop with the sum of the series 1 through i. We keep your first loop, and at each iteration add the sum of the series 1 through i to your previous value.

Note that I've added a `-2` to your outer loop to simulate the < sign in your two inner loops. If your requirement was <= on each inner loop then that `-2` would not be needed.

This is an O(n) solution, which is not as good as [Paul Hankin's O(1) solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37871365/3034198).